# Include Third party Charting plugins with ExtJs 5

Tags: extjs, highcharts, extjs5

I need to use thirdparty charting apps (like [highcharts](http://www.highcharts.com/)) in my Extjs 5 app.

Need inputs on how this can be achieved. Please provide any guides / plugins available.

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use wrapper for [extJs](https://github.com/JoeKuan/Highstock_ExtJs_4) for highcharts.

Comment: I was able to embed highcharts into extjs app using the plugin mentioned above.

Some references:
http://www.joekuan.org/
API Doc: http://www.joekuan.org/demos/Highcharts_Sencha/docs/